# testing route with parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using rspec to test my application 
I have a route with an id like this

```
  match 'promotevuln/moderate/:id' => 'moderate#promotevuln'
```

and here is the code that I test with

```
RSpec.describe ModerateController, :type => :controller do

  describe '#promotevuln' do
    context 'access controle' do
      before :each do
        @vuln=NewVulnerability.new(:description=>'description',:description_eng=>'description',:title=>'title',:title_eng=>'title_eng',:short_description=>'short',:short_description_eng=>'short')
      end

      it 'must be connected' do
        get :promotevuln,{:id=>@vuln.id}
        expect(response).to redirect_to(:controller => 'account', :action => 'login')
      end
```

but I was not able to pass this condition and it always returns this error message

```
Failure/Error: get :promotevuln,{:id=>@vuln.id}
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"moderate", :action=>"promotevuln"}
```

Comment: What's the value of `@vuln.id` before you call `get`?

Comment: It is an int the NewVulnerability enherit from ActiveRecord::Base so it is the id of the vulnerabilty in the data base

Comment: But what's it's **value**? nil? 1? 'Apple'?

Comment: it is an int auto incremented so let'say 500

Comment: Don't assume – check: `puts @vuln.id.inspect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating a new NewVulnerability but you're not persisting it to the database, so its `id` is `nil`.

Comment: Good to hear. A few simple `puts` statements are very effective for debugging!